# t-sql command parameter wildcard

Tags: c#, t-sql

I've read numerous similar questions, but the answers simply didn't work. Running this function in sql `select * from HelloRow('o')` returns no rows. Running `HelloRow('one')` returns the row with name "one". The fillrow method doesn't do anything (just reads the strings).

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "HelloFillRow", DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read, TableDefinition="message nchar(20)")]
public static IEnumerable HelloQuery(SqlString like)
{
    ArrayList resultCollection = new ArrayList();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand(
            "select name from test where name like @par"
            , connection))
        {
            select.Parameters.Add("par", SqlDbType.NChar, 10).Value = like + "%";
            using (SqlDataReader selectReader = select.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (selectReader.Read())
                {
                    SqlString nextName = selectReader.GetString(0);
                    resultCollection.Add(nextName.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return resultCollection;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure the problem is `NChar` vs `NVarchar`

Comment: Do you want a substring match?  In that case you need to wrap `like` in percent signs not just have a trailing one.

Comment: I noticed that you are adding your parameter to your command as 'par', not '@par'.  I would think that that would cause an issue, but you claim that calling your function with 'one' does work...

Comment: @JonSenchyna - It is optional.

Comment: I was guessing so, but I couldn't find any documentation stating that.  Can you please point me to some if you know of any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change command text to:

```
select name from test where name like @par + '%'
```

and add parameter as such:

```
select.Parameters.Add("par", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = like;
```

Comment: The issue is the trailing spaces for the fixed length parameter type.

Comment: this would amount to a curious insight to how like works (I'll try it shortly); why exactly does 'one%' match NChar(10) 'one' but 'o%' does not?

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same result -- correction, just forgot to change it in the `create external`